# BrokenPipeError: [Errno 32] Broken pipe on Windows and CUDA 10

Tags: python-3.x, anaconda, pytorch

I am able to run my program on system with CUDA 9.2, Quadro M5000 (5), and python 3.7.0 (anaconda) while the same program giving me an error on another system with the CUDA 10.0, GeForce GTX 1080 Ti (6), and python 3.7.1

here is the error

```
 ForkingPickler(file, protocol).dump(obj)

 BrokenPipeError: [Errno 32] Broken pipe
```

the whole code wrap in a function named train_valid_model() and just add the main guard in the script:

```
def train_valid_model():
# complete code here

 if __name__=='__main__':
     train_valid_model()
```

It only works when num_workers=0 and if I set it to 1 or 2 I will get this error. Any idea why I am getting this error while the program is same just the CUDA version and python version are different?

Comment: It's strange the error persists even after wrapping it inside `if __name__=='__main__':`. There was a similar question: https://stackoverflow.com/q/53974351/6210807