# Python Script is running itself twice

Tags: python, numpy, pytorch

I am learning PyTorch and working my way through the tutorials. I find that when I attempt to use torchvision my script is running twice. I wonder if it is configured wrong or I accidentally introduced some sort of parallelism.

Here is my code:

```
# show images
import torch
import torchvision
import torchvision.transforms as transforms
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

transform = transforms.Compose(
    [transforms.ToTensor(),
     transforms.Normalize((0.5, 0.5, 0.5), (0.5, 0.5, 0.5))])

trainset = torchvision.datasets.CIFAR10(root='./data', train=True,
                                        download=True, transform=transform)
trainloader = torch.utils.data.DataLoader(trainset, batch_size=4,
                                          shuffle=True, num_workers=2)

testset = torchvision.datasets.CIFAR10(root='./data', train=False,
                                       download=True, transform=transform)
testloader = torch.utils.data.DataLoader(testset, batch_size=4,
                                         shuffle=False, num_workers=2)

classes = ('plane', 'car', 'bird', 'cat',
           'deer', 'dog', 'frog', 'horse', 'ship', 'truck')

def imshow(img):
    img = img / 2 + 0.5     # unnormalize
    npimg = img.numpy()
    plt.imshow(np.transpose(npimg, (1, 2, 0)))
    plt.show()


# get some random training images
print('Type of trainloader')
print(type(trainloader))

dataiter = iter(trainloader)
images, labels = dataiter.next()

# show images
imshow(torchvision.utils.make_grid(images))
# print labels
print(' '.join('%5s' % classes[labels[j]] for j in range(4)))
```

My output is:

```
C:\Users\Avi\Anaconda3\python.exe C:/Users/Avi/PycharmProjects/ExampleNN/test.py
Files already downloaded and verified
Files already downloaded and verified
Type of trainloader
<class 'torch.utils.data.dataloader.DataLoader'>
Files already downloaded and verified
Files already downloaded and verified
Type of trainloader
<class 'torch.utils.data.dataloader.DataLoader'>
```

And then there is a crash on `dataiter = iter(trainloader)` the second time around, presumably because the iteration is finished already.

Can anyone tell me what I am doing wrong?

**UPDATE:**

I've discovered that if I set num_workers=0 in the DataLoader constructor it only runs once and has no crash. If I set it o 1, it runs twice and crashes just like when I set it to 2. I still don't understand why this is happening, but at least I can work around my issue.

Comment: are you importing this script in another script that you execute?

Comment: You have a pair of duplicate lines in your program at the trainset and testloader assignments.

Comment: @matyas This script is executed directly.

Comment: @DanD. Thanks. I saw that. Do those calls somehow cause a split in execution? I thought they were done sequentially? UPDATE: I removed one and the error still occurs. They do operate sequentially, so 'Files already downloaded and verified' now only outputs once for each of the two iterations.

Comment: You seem to be missing an `if __name__ == '__main__'` guard.

Comment: @user2357112 Intriguing. I'm very new to Python. Can you please elaborate? I just did some reading and I understand that the guard you are talking about would make sure that the guarded code is only ever called directly from the command-line. What code would wrap with the guard? All of it?

Comment: @AviChapman the error is due to multiprocessing issue. You can read [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53976426/6210807) and check corresponding links.